# Positioning 3 divs such that they appear as if placed inside a table row of 3 columns

Tags: html, xhtml, css

Previously, I was using `<table>` to split up my page layout into 3 parts, the left sidebar, right sidebar & the main centre panel. Now, after having learnt the disadvantages of overusing/misusing `<table>`, I want to avoid using tables for this purpose & I am looking to style these 3 `div`s in such a way that they look like 3 columns of a `<table>` row.

Any inputs on how I can achieve the 3 `div`s in same row, would be highly appreciated.

Currently my all the three `div` s are shown in linearized fashion, one after another.

Comment: Google "css 3 column layout", there are a million different sites.

Comment: are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/MZphm/

Comment: possible duplicate of [3 column layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450183/3-column-layout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something easier, what about:

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main{
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 960px; /*just an example*/
}
#main div{
    float: left;
    width: 320px; /* a third of the main width*/
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Typically sidebars have fixed width and the middel content area takes up the rest of the space. Considering that, here's the best approach:

```
<style>
#left {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
} #right {
    width:200px;
    float:right;
} #main {
    margin:0px 200px;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
  <div id="left">content</div>
  <div id="right">content</div>
  <div id="main">content</div>
</div>
```

Resize the window and all is well.

Working JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/7ayqe/

Answer (score 1):

Give them "float:left" properties and corresponding width to make it the size you want.

Example (I know these are inline styles, used for demonstration purposes only):

```
<div id="left-sidebar" style="width:30%;float:left"><!--Left Sidebar--></div>
<div id="content" style="width:50%;float:left"><!--Content--></div>
<div id="right-sidebar" style="width:20%;float:left"><!--Right Sidebar--></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you started:

```
<div>
    <div class="column">column one</div>   
    <div class="column">column two</div>   
    <div class="column">column three</div>
    <div class="last"></div>
</div>


.column { float: left; padding: 5px }
.last { clear: left}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/qXP37/) is a live example

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col1"></div>
<div class="col2"></div>
<div class="col3"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.col1 {
   float:left;
   width:250px;
}

.col2 {
   float:left;
   width:600px;
}

.col3 {
   float:left;
   width:20px;
}

.clear {
   clear:both;
}
```